# Android Studio Error when starting the software (missing toolbar, can't click anything, suddenly pop a new window)

Tags: android-studio

I don't know what happened. But when I want to open the android studio again, suddenly there are two windows. One totally blank and then in my project there's no toolbar and I can't even click anything.

Tried to uninstall and install the program but nothing seems to work.

**This is how it looks like:**

[image: issue-screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what cause this kind of error after restarting the android studio

but somehow, I found a little bit solution

just change the name of the software (studio64.exe) to any other name when it's happened. It fix the error but won't make any update.